# Click handler doesn't work in template-expanding directive

Tags: angularjs

[My application](http://jsfiddle.net/qdhau2zb/4/) has a custom template-expanding directive which is used to create several `section-toggle` elements.  The `section-toggle` elements represent buttons that the user clicks to toggle the display of one of several `section` elements on the page.

```
<div ng-controller="NavCtrl">

    <nav>
        <section-toggler toggle="section1">Toggle Section 1</section-toggler>
        <section-toggler toggle="section2">Toggle Section 2</section-toggler>
        <section-toggler toggle="section3">Toggle Section 3</section-toggler>
    </nav>

    <article>
        <section ng-show="shownSection == 'section1'">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</section>
        <section ng-show="shownSection == 'section2'">Mauris dignissim vehicula risus ac vestibulum.</section>
        <section ng-show="shownSection == 'section3'">Vivamus congue risus at tortor varius egestas.</section>
    </article>

</div>
```

My controller scope has a property called `shownSection` (a string that represents which section to show on the page) and a function called `toggleSection()`, which sets the value of `shownSection` to whatever value is present in the `toggle` attribute of the `section-toggler` element.

```
app.controller("NavCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.shownSection = 'section1';
    $scope.toggleSection = function(section) {
        $scope.shownSection = section; 
    };
});

app.directive('sectionToggler', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function(){
                scope.toggleSection(attrs["toggle"]);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the directive doesn't appear to change the controller's `$scope.shownSection` value, which would in turn show and hide the individual sections.

I thought that the `scope = false` in the directive definition object would force the directive to use `NavCtrl`'s scope, and that `attrs("toggle")` would get the value of the `section-toggler`'s `toggle` attribute.

To no avail, I have tried using `this.attr("toggle")` and `element.attr("toggle")` in place of `attrs["toggle"]` (none of which work), and I've tried changing `$scope.shownSection = section` in the controller to `shownSection = section`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdhau2zb/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the section togglers do in fact change `$scope.shownSection`. You can verify this by adding `console.log($scope.shownSection)` at the bottom of the `$scope.toggleSection` function.

The problem is that `bind` (as in `element.bind("click"`) is a jqLite/jQuery function which does not trigger Angular's digest loop. It's when the digest loop runs that Angular will update the UI to reflect the updated model values.

To trigger it manually you can for example use `$apply`:

```
element.bind("click", function () {
  scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.toggleSection(attrs["toggle"]);
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qdhau2zb/6/

Comment: Thank you, this answer was *incredibly* helpful and enlightening. I guess the other issue I was having was that I was not including `ng-app` in my JSFiddle; this threw me off pretty badly.

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, the `ng-app` threw me off as well. I was going to comment on it but I apparently forgot :)